# Match specific string, except when it contains certain text

Tags: regex

I'm working with urls and have a simple working regex

```
^go\/([_0-9a-z-])+
```

which matches anything that starts with "go/"

I now need to extend this so it still matches that, but now only if it doesn't contain another string - in this case ".aspx" (ie I'm trying to match folders, but not filenames)

So successful matches would include

```
go/test1
go/test2
```

and unsuccessful ones would include

```
go/test3.aspx
go/test4.aspx?param
stop/test5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
^go\/([_0-9a-z-])+$
```

The `$` matches the end of the string, so no more characters allowed. If you only want to match strings that don't have ".something" after, then you can use [look-arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the `+` inside the capturing group if you want to match everything after `go/`
2. Define a second, optional capturing group for `.aspx`. Filtering out matches where this second group is not null. Regex isn't the only programming language in town.

Pattern and [stub](https://regex101.com/r/cG0nY9/1):

```
^go\/([_0-9a-z-]+)(\.aspx)?
```

Comment: Overly complex for what is needed